# how to validate / lint styled-jsx in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stylelint, css-in-js, styled-jsx

I am using nextJS for development, for [stylelint](https://stylelint.io/) to validate my `.scss` and `.css` files.
I'm also using `styled-jsx` or `css-in-js` for component level styling (it's kind of requirement) and want to know if there's some library to validate `styled-jsx` below is the code sample of my css code.

```
<style jsx>{`
          .HeadText {
              color: ${myColors['color-primary']};
          }
`}
</style>
```

I've tried using [this](https://github.com/mapbox/stylelint-processor-arbitrary-tags) library but it work's for only static styles like below :

```
<style jsx>{`
          .HeadText {
              color: red;
              bad-property: something; // gives error
          }
`}
</style>
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but you can define `myColors['color-primary']` as `:root { --color-primary: brown; }` in your global css, then use it as var: `.HeadText  { color: var(--color-primary); }`